# How to separate debezium metrics by source table?

Tags: debezium, jmx-exporter

I use debezium postgres connector (docker) with JMX. Everything works fine. The Dockerfile from which the image is built is this:

```
ARG DEBEZIUM_VERSION
FROM debezium/connect:${DEBEZIUM_VERSION}

ARG JMX_AGENT_VERSION
RUN mkdir /kafka/etc && cd /kafka/etc &&\
        curl -so jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar \
        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/prometheus/jmx/jmx_prometheus_javaagent/$JMX_AGENT_VERSION/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-$JMX_AGENT_VERSION.jar

COPY config.yml /kafka/etc/config.yml
```

config.yml

```yaml
startDelaySeconds: 0
ssl: false
lowercaseOutputName: false
lowercaseOutputLabelNames: false
rules:
- pattern : "kafka.connect<type=connect-worker-metrics>([^:]+):"
  name: "kafka_connect_worker_metrics_$1"
- pattern : "kafka.connect<type=connect-metrics, client-id=([^:]+)><>([^:]+)"
  name: "kafka_connect_metrics_$2"
  labels:
    client: "$1"
- pattern: "debezium.([^:]+)<type=connector-metrics, context=([^,]+), server=([^,]+), key=([^>]+)><>RowsScanned"
  name: "debezium_metrics_RowsScanned"
  labels:
    plugin: "$1"
    name: "$3"
    context: "$2"
    table: "$4"
- pattern: "debezium.([^:]+)<type=connector-metrics, context=([^,]+), server=([^>]+)>([^:]+)"
  name: "debezium_metrics_$4"
  labels:
    plugin: "$1"
    name: "$3"
    context: "$2"
```

Both of these are taken directly from an [official example](https://github.com/debezium/debezium-examples/tree/main/monitoring)

The issue if that only RowsScanned metric has "table" label, all others do not. Other mbeans do not have a key set, so there is nowhere to extract the table name from.

I want metrics like TotalNumberOfCreateEventsSeen to have this label as well. Is there a way do it?